# Encoding URL issue

Tags: encoding, http-status-code-404, url-routing, persian

I use XAMPP v3.2.1 and routing is fine for all URLs except when there is `م` in the URL. *(`م` is a Persian character)*.

For e.g. the routhing of this URL is 404 Not Found:

```
localhost/FolderName/ClassName/MethodName/arg1/سلام%20بر
//                                 if I remove this ^ character, everything will be fine
```

Output of that URL:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /myweb/islamic_sources/quran/843/Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø¨Ø± was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 Server at localhost Port 80
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you pipe the value through str_replace like so

```
$oldurl = '...._persian_character_ ....';
$newurl = str_replace('_persian_character_', '', $oldurl);
```

Comment: Why should I remove Persian characters? I need to them ... I get it as a argument and use it in the query

Comment: perhaps I got distracted reading 'if I remove this all works...' have you tried unicode?

Comment: Ah, I understand why you misunderstood it ... But Actually I need it, I said *"I works fine if I remove it"* because I wanted to say the problem is from that specific character .

Comment: %20 stands for space. I don't see how you would need a space but well. In this case str_replace('%20', ' ', $oldurl) may help -- sorry, it's actually 20% - LTR I guess?

Comment: Yes `%20` means {space}, I need to it because that word is made of two parts like `made up`. And there is a space between `made` and `up`. Also I need to that space .. Actually I need to that last argument exactly as is. btw, removing that space not make something better.

Comment: then you'll probably want to wrap the string within quotes